# Object has members variables values changed after push operation to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, strategy-pattern

I have a `std::vector<Item*> listOfItems` which holds pointers to `Item` objects.

I have two parameters for the constructor of `Item` ,

```
Item::Item(std::string name, int amount)
{
    itemName = name;
    ownerAmount = amount;       
}
```

I also have `Player` objects, which have a member variable `std::vector<Item> ownedItems`.

I've created in my main file a vector with pointers to all the `Item` objects owned by the various `Player` declared as follow:

```
std::vector<Item*> itemList = listOfItems(players);
```

where

```
std::vector<Item*> listOfItems(std::vector<Player*> players) {
    std::vector<Item*> listOfItems itemList;
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < players.at(i)->getAllCountries()->size(); j++) {
            itemList.push_back(&players.at(i)->getAllCountries()->at(j));
        }
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

After this is declared, I'm running the strategy of my Player which is:

```
    player1->executeStrategy(&itemList);
```

Now in the doOperation (following the Strategy Pattern) of my player declared as follow:

```
    void HumanPlayerStrategy::doOperation(Item* x, std::vector<Item*> *itemList){
                    attackerVictory(x, itemList);   
}
```

I'm running the function `attackerVictory` with a pointer to the `itemList` declared in main with all the pointers to the various `Item` owned by the different `Player`(for the purpose of modifying these).

The only problem is, after I'm done doing operations in attackerVictory, any `Item` that is added to the `itemList` has blank member variable values.
I can't seem to grasp why this would not work?

Here is my attackerVictory function:

```
void Strategy::attackerVictory(Item* x, std::vector<Item*> *listOfItems) {
    Item temp = *x;
    /* set different member variable values for the Item temp */
    listOfItems->push_back(&temp);
}
```

Doing so gives me am `Item` at the end if the `listOfItems` with empty `itemName` and `ownerAmount` values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Read about iterator invalidations

Comment: Do **not** store pointers to internal vector items.  If that vector is resized, those pointers you stored can become invalid.  Example: `vector<int> x; x.push_back(10); int *ptr = &x[0]; x.push_back(20);`  That `ptr` may not point to valid memory if the vector `x` changes size.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules).

Comment: You push pointers to stack variables... boom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding reference to a temporary object which gets destroyed after the attackerVictory method is executed.  It should be

```
void Strategy::attackerVictory(Item* x, std::vector<Item*> *listOfItems){
    Item * tempptr = new Item();
    *tempptr = *x;

    listOfItems->push_back(tempptr);
}
```

Comment: A problem, but not the only problem. There is a pretty nasty architectural deficiency that needs to be resolved.  Other than that, you can kill two birds with one stone. Take advantage of the copy constructor (`Item * tempptr = new Item(*x);`) rather than construct then assign.